# Is it possible to create Web Service in Java that can use Amazon cognito and SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-cognito

Can I build a server in java(exposes Web Services to Mobile or Web client) which uses Amazon Cognito for Identity Management, Cognito Sync to sync across all devices and SNS push notification. NOTE: I want all congnito and SNS code on server and want to expose them as web service also.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are Java AWS SDKs for the modules you mention: [cognito for identity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cognitoidentity/AmazonCognitoIdentity.html), [cognito sync](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cognitosync/package-summary.html), and [SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/package-summary.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you please explain how to architect this. I want to use rdbms to all apps data which will be queried through server I mentioned above. I am confuse about sync part. let's say user create an object on iPhone and put it into rdbms, How can I sync that instantly to his/her other devices ?

Comment: ...you need to write the application. Stackoverflow isn't the correct venue to request fully working projects.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't asking for full project, I am confuse about whether to sync using server or device sdk